# Отправка ветки из Git-репозитория в SVN-репозиторий

Tags: git, svn, контроль-версий, git-svn, git-репозиторий

Можно ли отправить ветку в удаленный SVN-репозиторий из локального Git-репозитория?

В данный момент работаю с git-репозиторием в нескольких ветках.

```
$ git remote -v
origin  git@mysite.com:repo.git (fetch)
origin  git@mysite.com:repo.git (push)

$ git branch -a
  master
* develop
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/develop
```

Возникла необходимость отправить определенную ветку, допустим, `develop` в SVN.

Поиск ответа в сети предлагает кучу инфы по импорту и клонированию из SVN в Git, а не наоборот.

Возможно, я привык к гитовской логике работы, но можно просто добавить SVN-репу в качестве удаленного хранилища и запушить ветку туда?

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как действовать

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/746151/2076787

Comment: @D-side добавить репу я смогу, а как отправить ветку в SVN?

Comment: Как обычно, `git push ремоут откуда:куда`. Наверное. Ну, традиционно гит работает так, не знаю есть ли у SVN в этой области какие-то детали.

Comment: С svn можно общаться используя git-svn (init конфигурирует `[svn-remote]`, dcommit желаемую ветку отправляет). Если init поверх существующего git репозитория к нежелательным побочным эффектам ведёт, то попробуйте просто блок `[svn-remote]` из `.git/config` скопировать. Конфигурация по умолчанию (trunk/tags/branches) вам не подойдёт, так что явно аргументы init передайте.

Comment: @jfs какие значения нужно передавать в -t/-T/-b ит почему дефолтные не подойдут?

Comment: Я же явно написал: по умолчанию git svn будет пытаться и trunk и tags и branches отображать из svn в git. Вы (насколько я понял) хотите только одну ветку из git куда-нибудь в svn положить (проще).  Суть в том сконфигурированные удалённые папки в svn (давно с svn не работал, не уверен за терминологию) соответствуют веткам (branches) в  git — связь двухсторонняя git svn fetch из svn в git, и git svn dcommit в svn из git.

Answer (score 1):

Решение следующее (необходима версия git>2.3.0). Клонируем репозиторий, если у вас еще нет локальной копии, и продолжаем работу с ним.

Добавляем удаленный svn-репозиторий путем правки файла `.git/config`, добавляем в файл запись

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
  url = https://my-repo.com/svn/path/to/my/trunk
  fetch = :refs/remotes/trunk
```

Стягиваем изменения из svn-репозитория по последнюю ревизию

```
git svn fetch svn -r HEAD
```

Результат команды `git branch -a` должен выглядеть так

```
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/master
remotes/trunk
```

Создаем локально ветку, которая будет связана с веткой svn-репозитория, и переходим в нее

```
git checkout -b release remotes/trunk
```

С полученной веткой можно выполнять разлчиный операции, например, объединить с `master` веткой

```
git merge develop --allow-unrelated-histories
```

Полученные изменения можно влить обратно в svn-репозиторий (мы продолжаем находится на ветке, которая связана с svn-репозиторием)

```
git svn dcommit
```

Приведенные команды позволили, в моем случае, решить проблему синхронизации git-svn и объединения результа работы двух комманд программистов

Comment: svn с нелинейной историей не дружило когда я ею пользовался. Поэтому merge лучше проводить на отдельной ветке, чтобы можно было спрямить историю: `git co release; git svn rebase; git co -b merging_release; git merge develop; git rebase -i release #(линеаризация)` после этого спрямлённую ветку можно сливать: `git co release; git merge merging_release; git svn dcommit; git branch -D merging_release` [Git SVN and merging branches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4290855/4279) (ответу седьмой год, может сейчас получше что есть)

Comment: @jfs может я чего-то не понимаю, но я же мерджу на локальной отдельной ветке release. разве не так?

Comment: `release` у вас это ветка, на которой вы `git svn rebase` (стянуть), `git svn dcommit` (оправить) выполняете, поэтому чтобы проблем не создавать, эта ветка должна иметь простую линеаризованную историю, значит `git merge develop` на ней не следует делать.